# How to post data into a specific url or server

Tags: ios7

I want to build up a login page and the values of this page i want to submit in server through a specific link. can any one send the code that how i will send the data into server?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example using NSURLConnection to send POST parameters:

```
// Note that the URL is the "action" URL parameter from the form.
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL @"http://www.whereq.com:8079/answer.m"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
//this is hard coded based on your suggested values, obviously you'd probably need to make this more dynamic based on your application's specific data to send
NSString *postString = @"paperid=6&q77=2&q80=blah";
NSData *data = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[request setHTTPBody:data];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", [data length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Comment: Thanks jacob..But problem is you know, i can't understand [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"]; and NSString *postString = @"paperid=6&q77=2&q80=blah";
NSData *data = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; this two fields..What should i written in my code.?

Comment: and which delegate method i have to add..?